# Predicting reactions problem

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: g]

I am not sure where to begin with this problem. I feel Br carries negative charge and is this gonna be no reaction since the alpha carbon is $sp^2$?

Comment: On the contrary,the large negative charge density on the vinylic group will be much more reactive(due to the relatively higher instability of the anion),and hence it will be much more prone to be attracted towards the positively charged carbonyl carbon and perform an addition

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reagent#Reactions_of_Grignard_reagents will point you in the right direction...

Comment: The reagent 1 is a Grignard reagent and your substrate is a ketone. Sounds familiar?

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Ok let me see.